# How to return the data in one function call for two different object keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an object which looks like this :

```
const data = {
  students: [{
    code: '1',
    number: '22',
    type: 'regular',
    name: 'john',
    age: '11',
    class: 'A',
  }, {
    code: '2',
    number: '23',
    type: 'regular',
    name: 'steve',
    age: '12',
    class: 'B',
  }],
  teachers: [{
    code: '22',
    number: '101',
    type: 'intern',
    name: 'mac',
  }, {
    code: '23',
    number: '102',
    type: 'perm',
    name: 'jess',
  }],
};
```

It has different keys and values.

Here, I am trying to massage this data so that I can obtain the following result: So I am trying to get an array which will have only students data and other which will have teachers data from one function itself.

```
const result1 = [{
  code: '1',
  number: '22',
  type: 'regular',
  name: 'john',
}, {
  code: '2',
  number: '23',
  type: 'regular',
  name: 'steve',
}];
const result2 = [{
  code: '22',
  number: '101',
  type: 'intern',
  name: 'mac',
}, {
  code: '23',
  number: '102',
  type: 'perm',
  name: 'jess',
}];
```

what I tried is :

```
const getData = ({data = []}) => {
 data?.map({ code,
number, 
regular, 
name } ) => {
return{
code,
number, 
regular, 
name
}}
}

getData(data.students)
getData(data.teachers)   // How do get this data in one function call itself
```

This gives me the result , but for this I need to call this function twice once for students and one for teachers. I want to call this function once.

Thanks

Comment: Just return `data`?

Comment: No , But I wanted to pass this data to seperate components. and with the specific fields

Comment: "I want to call this function once" So create a function that does what `getData` does, call it something different (say `transformData`), then rewrite `getData` to do `return { students: transformData(data.students), teachers: transformData(data.teachers) };` Then you're only calling `getData` once and getting both results back...

Comment: can you please put in solution @HereticMonkey

Comment: There you go, answered.

Comment: @ganeshk ... Regarding all the answers / approaches are there any questions left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map new entries from the object and take the mapped new structure.

```js
const
    data = { students: [{ code: '1', number: '22', type: 'regular', name: 'john', age: '11', class: 'A' }, { code: '2', number: '23', type: 'regular', name: 'steve', age: '12', class: 'B' }], teachers: [{ code: '22', number: '101', type: 'intern', name: 'mac' }, { code: '23', number: '102', type: 'perm', name: 'jess' }] },
    getData = ({ code, number, regular, name }) => ({ code, number, regular, name }),
    result = Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(data)
        .map(([k, v]) => [k, v.map(getData)])
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: is there any other way for this , as if at first data is not there then Object.Fromentries whill be undefined

Comment: what other data do you have? actually it expects an object with properties of arrays.

Comment: Hey @Nina I got the solution, is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: I updated some part of questions, can you plese check

Comment: sorry, i don't understand the problem.

Comment: So I am getting a prototype object  as a result

Answer (score 0):

Since from the provided data, it looks like the OP wants to *mainly [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) a certain set of properties* of student/teacher items from a map/object, a possible approach is to [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the `data` object's [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and apply the mapping exclusively for a matching `students` or `teachers` key each referring to a valid array-type value.

```js
const data = {
  students: [{ code: "1", number: "22", type: "regular", name: "john", age: "11", class: "A" }, { code: "2", number: "23", type: "regular", name: "steve", age: "12", class: "B" }],
  teachers: [{ code: "22", number: "101", type: "intern", name: "mac" }, { code: "23", number: "102", type: "perm", name: "jess" }],
};

const {

  students: result1,
  teachers: result2,

} = Object
  .entries(data)
  .reduce((result, [key, value]) => {
    if (
      // process only for a matching key ...
      (/^students|teachers$/).test(key)

      // ... and a valid value type.
      && Array.isArray(value)
    ) {
      result[key] = value
        .map(({ code, number, type, name }) =>
          ({ code, number, type, name })
        );
    }
    return result
  }, {});

console.log({ result1, result2 });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure what use there is in this, but since you want to run a function twice and get two results, do that, and combine into an object:

```js
const data = {
  students: [{
    code: '1',
    number: '22',
    type: 'regular',
    name: 'john',
    age: '11',
    class: 'A'
  }, {
    code: '2',
    number: '23',
    type: 'regular',
    name: 'steve',
    age: '12',
    class: 'B'
  }],
  teachers: [{
    code: '22',
    number: '101',
    type: 'intern',
    name: 'mac'
  }, {
    code: '23',
    number: '102',
    type: 'perm',
    name: 'jess'
  }]
};
const transformData = (data = []) =>
  data.map(({
    code,
    number,
    regular,
    name
  }) => ({
    code,
    number,
    regular,
    name
  }));
const getData = (data) =>
  ({
    students: transformData(data.students),
    teachers: transformData(data.teachers)
  });
console.log(getData(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Note: I modified the `transformData` function to remove some extra syntax, and to remove the optional chaining since the Stack Snippets' ancient version of Babel doesn't support it.

Also, there's no property named `regular` on the original objects in the array, so they come out undefined.

Comment: Hey I tried this, But not sure why it gives me empty array everytime I guess is there anything related to the spread operator

Comment: Yeah, you shouldn't need the spread syntax for anything.

Answer (score -3):

Based on the input and output looks like you're just trying to slice off the keys `age` and `class` from the objects. So you'd just need to iterate through both the keys then the underlying objects to remove them.

```js
const getData = (data) => {
  Object.keys(data).forEach(function callback(key) {
    let value = data[key];

    value.forEach(function callback(obj) {
      let blockArray = ['age', 'class'];
      blockArray.forEach(e => delete obj[e]);
    });
  });

  return data;
}

const updatedData = getData(data);

const result1 = updatedData.students;
console.dir(result1);

const result2 = updatedData.teachers;
console.dir(result2);
```